# Visual Studio Publishing Excluding Folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, publishing

Inside the publish profile (pubxml) created by VS you can add an exclude tag like the following:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Themes;Core;Media</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

Obviously this excludes these folders from being published. I would like to use a wildcard if possible to exclude folders that start with certain text. So Imagine I have a Modules folder that contains dozens of folders some starting test. I want to exclude these folders from being published. I was expecting to use a syntax like:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Themes;Core;Media;Modules\Test*</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

but by the fact I'm asking this question you know it doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: A bit old, but I have the exact same question - did you find a resolution? As an aside, were you doing Orchard development in the above examples? Looks like it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **MS Build wildcards** to specify what to exclude.

If something like this doesn't work:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Themes;Core;Media;Modules\Test\**</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

Then find a way to exlude all the files... maybe like so:

```
<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>Modules\Test\**\*.*</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
```

EDIT: 
Here's a link that may help: "MSBuild Items", https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Wildcards

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't exclude the folders or files. My problem is/was a node_modules directory. It seems to work for *other* folders. But not node_modules for whatever reason. Just throws the directory names are too long error.